# Save highscore in localstorage (Javascript snake game)

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, cordova

So the problem I'm having is rather simple and yet I can't seem to get it to work within all the functions.
I simply want the highscore to be saved in the localstorage and automatically updated when the game is over.
I'm thankful for any specific solutions! Thanks!

Bonus question: The game should work on android (cordova) - hence the button controls. However, there seems to be a short delay when tapping a button. This is not the case when using the keyboard. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use window.localStorage object.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('highscore', JSON.stringify({userName: 'test', score: 100500}));

var score = window.localStorage.getItem('highscore')

if(score){
    var scoreObj = JSON.parse(score);
    console.log(scoreObj.score);
}
```